# Showing nothing in display, using Yii 2.0.6

Tags: php, yii2

I am using YII 2.0.6 basic, code for the three files is as :-

model file namely 'UserForm.php'

```
namespace app\models;

    use yii\base\Model;

    class UserForm extends Model
    {
        public $name;
        public $email;

        public function rules()
        {
            return[
                    [['name','email'],'required'],
                    ['email','email']
                  ];
        }
    }
```

controller file namely 'SiteController.php'

```
public function actionUser()
    {
        $model = new UserForm;

        if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate())
        {
            Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','You have entered the data correctly.');
        }
        $this->render('user',['model'=>$model]);
```

and the third one view file namely 'user.php'

```
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\widgets\ActiveForm;

if(Yii::$app->session->hasFlash('success'))
{
   echo Yii::$app->getFlash('success');
}

$form = ActiveForm::begin()
<? $form->field($model,'name'); ?>
<? $form->form($model,'email'); ?>
<? Html::submitButton('Submit',['class' => 'btn btn-success']); ?>
ActiveForm::end()
```

I am using this link in the browser to get the data displayed. Well I think this link is correct.

http://localhost/basic/web/index.php?r=site/user

When I goes to this link, The browser shows nothing, neither an error nor any output.

May anybody please help me out, where is the exact problem ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should use return in your `actionUser`

this way :

```
public function actionUser()
{
    $model = new UserForm;

    if($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())&& $model->validate())
    {
        Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success','You have entered the data correctly.');
    }
    return $this->render('user',['model'=>$model]);  // return here
```

Comment: Thank if this is useful for you. in addition to accepting the answer you can mark it as useful by voting the up arrow.